# string concatenation with property binding in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular2-template

in Angular 2 we have several way to create property bindings in templates.
I could do something like this:

```
<li *ngFor="#course of courses; #i = index" id="someselector-{{i}}">{{course}}</li>
```

Is it possible to obtain the same result using the square brakets syntax?

```
<li *ngFor="#course of courses; #i = index" [id]="someselector-i">{{course}}</li>
                                            ^^^^^^^
                                  how create string concatenation?
```

Thanks,
G.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I found out that you can use this kind of syntax using square brackets:

```
<li *ngFor="#course of courses; #i = index" [id]="'someselector-'+i">{{course}}</li>
```

For more information, please have a look to this interesting article from Pascal Precht: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/08/11/angular-2-template-syntax-demystified-part-1.html